# Why is DC sqrt(2) higher than AC after rectifing?

Tags: rectifier

I've Googled this question (and similar questions) but cannot find an answer that I can understand.

My theory was, mathematically speaking, that it would be 1.41 times higher because you get the peak of the sine wave after rectification.  Is this correct?

Comment: Rectification (assuming full wave and ideal diodes) does not change the RMS voltage. A sinusoidal 10V RMS voltage has peaks of +/-14.14V. After rectification it will still be 10V RMS- the heating value does not change. Add a capacitor and things change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rectify a sine wave and then smooth it with a capacitor you get something like this: -

[image]

If the load is "light" the red line has less ripple. Ultimately, with no load there is no ripple and the red trace is a flat line at the peak of the sine wave.

The peak of a sine wave is \$\sqrt2\$ times higher than the RMS value.

> My theory was, mathematically speaking, that it would be 1.41 times
>   higher because you "stretch" the sine wave of 1 period and get higher
>   potential because of "keeping the lenght". Would that be a coincidence
>   or a possibility of explanation?

No, that's not a sensible explanation - there is no sine wave stretching and even if there were it would be for half a period for full-wave rectification.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that AC voltages are most often represented in terms of RMS.  So the peak voltage of a 120VAC (rms) signal is higher than 120V, it is ~170V.  When you rectify and assuming there is some bulk capacitor to store the peaks, you will see that voltage in DC.  The concept of RMS is that the 120Vrms AC source should have the same power flowing as 120VDC, even though the peak voltage is 170V.

Answer (score 2):

> My theory was,

An ideal diode will continue to charge the capacitor until the output reaches the peak input voltage.

With a load and forward voltage drop of the diode, the output vooktage starts to become lower than the input peak voltage.